# How can I make comments in external library available in code that reference it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio / monodevelop have awesome feature that can let you specify xml comments above every function / variable which is then displayed as a description of that function when you roll over it, click it etc.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is example for stack overflow
    /// </summary>
    public void Foo()
    {

    }
```

This is cool, but it works only in your local code (within 1 project) how can I make these comments that are in functions in external library, which is referenced in another project, available in THAT project as well? It should be possible, because it works for .Net assemblies (when you reference a .Net library, you will be able to see these descriptions for functions in that library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the xml for documentation of your library using visual studio, check it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4sa0ak0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> The Generate XML documentation file property determines whether an XML
>   file will be generated during compilation. You set this property on
>   the Compile page (for Visual Basic) or Build page (for Visual C#) of
>   the Project Designer. When this option is selected, XML documentation
>   is automatically emitted into an XML file, which will have the same
>   name as your project and the .xml extension, [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4sa0ak0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: You will need to put it in the directory where related assembly exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/doc` and then bundle the generated documentation with your assemblies:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3260k4x7.aspx

Comment: this is important information, because for example monodevelop doesn't have "Generate XML documentation file" in build options, but you can append /doc to compiler parameters, +1